# better way of Json Parsing in UWP

Tags: json, performance, parsing, uwp, json.net

Need to know, if there is a better/best way to follow in order to make json parsing fatser.

I am dealing with huge json data can be in terms of up to 3~4mb.

I know by using jsonobject to object mapping is faster. But there is some dependency so couldnt use.

Current way of dealing with this huge data is,

```
            JToken value;
            dynamic item;                

            if (item.TryGetValue("DELAY_ID", out value))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                {
                    DelayId = (int)value;
                }
            }
```

I had to do null checks. This way of searching is done for all the key value pairs.

Not sure if I am doing correct.

Please guide/point me to the right path.

Regards,

Rummy

Comment: When the same json is parsed using iOS Dictionary. it is reduced by 50%. Not really sure, if objective C does some real fast job compared to .NET

Answer (score 1):

The go-to Library for JSON serialisation and deserialization is Json.Net. Search for it in Nuget.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json

Best thing is you don't need to add any extra attributes to your classes.

Here is the documentation.
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: The Newtonsoft.Json not the fastest way.

Comment: According to [Json.NET Website](http://json.net) it is faster than `DataContractJsonSerializer` and `JavaScriptSerializer`.